# Detect faulty voltage regulator on x3650 M4

Tags: ibm, ibm-xseries, xserver, lenovo

I have an IBM x3650 M4 which unfortunately falls within the condition of [Lenovo errata HT118532](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht118532/), that means at any reboot the voltage regulator might fall for overvoltage. While we figure out how to upgrade it (as all the tools available seems to fail with current OSes), is there any way to understand if the regulator is already compromised?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to describes what will happen if the voltage regulator fails: The system will fail to power on, with the LEDs blinking as described, and the messages shown there will be shown in IMM (which will continue to work). If this happens, it is too late and you'll have to replace the motherboard. You should not power off or reset the system until you are able to update the firmware.

Comment: The system runs VMware so I cannot update the firmware *on line*, I must create a bootable device, so I have no other options than reboot.

Comment: @Maxxer Obviously you'll have to reboot. But I didn't say reboot. I said reset. Do not hit the reset switch.

Comment: What's the difference between reset and reboot, in this case? The errata speaks about either poweroff or reboot

Comment: @Maxxer Rebooting just reboots the system. Reset resets all the hardware. Some people don't carefully distinguish between these, though they are two different processes.